# Does java have Transferable Objects (Multi Threading Concept)

Tags: java, multithreading

Javascript has [Transferable Objects](http://w3c.github.io/html/infrastructure.html#transferable-objects) used to transfer an object to a web worker without copying for thread safety.  Copying is not needed since the application no longer has a reference to the object, once the web worker has it.  In other words the reference is either held by the worker or the application, but not both of them at the same time.  Is there a similar mechanism in Java?

Comment: No, but we have locks. :) And if your object implements some kind of interface, you can also create a proxy object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, java does not have Transferable Objects as per the definition, because there is nothing in the JVM that can prevent two reference values from referring to the same instance.

<sub>However, there exist various kinds of builders, (see [Builder Pattern, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)) which can be used to construct an object, and then build an immutable instance out of it, which is then thread safe by virtue of being immutable. The most famous builder is `StringBuilder`.  I do not know of any other builders that java comes with out of the box, but I know there are many libraries that have builders, for example [Guava (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava), see `ImmutableMap.Builder<K,V>` ([Google guava documentation](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.Builder.html)).</sub>

Comment: I think that it's misleading to introduce immutable objects as a by-product of builders. Sure, some immutable objects need builders, but a great many others (like `String`, `Integer` etc) don't.

Comment: Also, why the `<sub>`?

Comment: @AndyTurner `Integer` of course doesn't need a builder, but how can you say that `String` doesn't?  What is the purpose of `StringBuilder` then?

Comment: `"Hello world"`. No builder there. You *can* construct a `String` with a `StringBuilder`, but you don't need to.

Comment: @AndyTurner I used `<sub>` because the text in `<sub>` is off-topic.  The OP wants to know about Transferable Objects.  Immutable objects have nothing to do with Transferable Objects.  They are just what we use in lieu of Transferable Objects.

Comment: In that case, I'd say "aside" or "off-topic"; making it smaller just looks like some weird rendering bug. But I don't think that it's really off-topic to say that immutability is the alternative that removes the need for TOs as a means of avoiding thread safety issues, because there can be no thread safety issues when using them.

Comment: @AndyTurner I have been using `<sub>` every once in a while for years.  I will take your note into account, (and thank you for it,) but I will wait until I hear more persons expressing a dislike towards `<sub>` before I abandon it.

Comment: It is also worth noting that if you use a factory of sorts to create your objects, you can create objects that delegate to a single underlying object, and never give out the reference to "the real object", thus maintaining full control over who can call methods on it at all times. Combined with locks this can work pretty well, although a certain amount of cooperation is still needed even those cases due to the reasons in your answer.